IWebHostBuilder.UseSetting doesn't replace original setting in WebApplicationFactory<Program>
Originally I had this code in ConfigureWebHost of the WebApplicationFactory<Program>:
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == 
        typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext>));
    var npgsqlDs = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(NpgsqlDataSource));

    services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);
    services.Remove(npgsqlDs);

    services.AddNpgsqlDataSource(_appDbConnectionString);
    services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(_appDbConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
});

But then I realized there is the UseSetting method that can simplify the process of the replacing the real connection string with the one created by Testcontainers.
But the value resolved in the Program is still the one defined in the appsettings.json, not the one I passed in UseSetting:
builder.UseSetting("ConnectionStrings:AppDatabase", _appDbConnectionString);

I added a new setting, and it appeared in the list of configurations. So adding new values works, replacing existing values doesn't work.
